# When can we treat the $i$ in a function $f: R \to \mathbb{C}$ as a "constant" when integrating

Tags: complex-analysis

It seems that for some nice functions, we can use the standard rules of integration (treating $i$ as a constant). For example $\int e^{it}=\frac{e^{it}}{i}$, however if it was $\int \frac{e^{it}}{i+e^{it}}$ i could not use the same "technique". I cannot do a $u=e^{it}$ sub, since then i would get a logarithm. Where do things break down and when can we treat $i$ as a constant and integrate as if it was a real function.

Comment: Why can't you?  $-i$ is still a constant.

Comment: @Randall fair enough, i will edit the problem function :P

Comment: Now your title and body are asking two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

The number $i$ is a constant. So, you can always treat is as constant, since it *is* one! What's peculiar with the substitution $u=e^{it}$ is that it is not bijective, but this has nothing to do with the number $i$. You also cannot do the substitution $u=x^2$ with $x\in[-1,1]$ for the same reason: $x\mapsto x^2$ is not a bijection in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: That's interesting. How i saw integration defined for such functions is you split it up into real and imaginary part, then integrate them separately. Is there a theorem that allows you to treat $i$ as a constant, and you do not have to split it up?

Comment: Since $i$ is a constant, I don't think that anyone ever bothered to write out a theorem saying that it can be treated as a constant, much like there is not theorem saying that $\pi$ can be treated as a constant, or that $\sqrt3$ can be treated as a constant.